# PivotTable creation problem from a dataframe

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, ms-office

I'm struggling with a code problem since yesterday. I dont get why I've got the following error message on line 3 : " Run-Time Error '5': Invalid Procedure Call or Argument"

Context: I'm trying to build a PivotTable on sheet called "test 2" from an data source sheet called "Extract".

Here's hereafter my VBA code:

```
Sub creation_TCD()
'

     Sheets("Extract").Select
    Columns("A:L").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Extract!A:L", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion16).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="test 2! A1", TableName:="pt10", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion16
    Sheets("test 2").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pt10").PivotFields( _
        "UNIT")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pt10").PivotFields( _
        "LAST_OPERATOR")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pt10").PivotFields( _
        "DECISION_TYPE")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pt10").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
        PivotTables("pt10").PivotFields("Nbre"), "Nombre de Nbre" _
        , xlCount
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pt10").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
        PivotTables("pt10").PivotFields("Time opérateur"), _
        "Nombre de Time opérateur", xlCount
    Range("C8").Select
    Range("E12").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pt10").NullString = "0"
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
    Range("C5").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pt10").PivotSelect _
        "'Nombre de Time opérateur'", xlDataAndLabel, True
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pt10").PivotFields( _
        "Nombre de Time opérateur")
        .Caption = "Somme de Time opérateur"
        .Function = xlSum
    End With
    Range("B5").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pt10").PivotSelect _
        "'Nombre de Nbre'", xlDataAndLabel, True
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pt10").PivotFields( _
        "Nombre de Nbre")
        .Caption = "Somme de Nbre"
        .Function = xlSum
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pt10").PivotFields( _
        "DECISION_TYPE   ")
        .PivotItems("NEW             ").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pt10").PivotFields( _
        "LAST_OPERATOR").CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pt10").PivotFields( _
        "LAST_OPERATOR")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pt10").PivotFields( _
        "LAST_OPERATOR").EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    Range("B8").Select

End Sub
```

Could somebody help me out ? I feel like there 's a silly mistake, but can't solve it.

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: LINE 3 after "Sub Creation_TCD()"

Comment: Maybe try to apply some of the guidelines from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?r=Saves_AllUserSaves